# howto make divs expand around fixed-sized div?

Tags: css, html

I want to frame a div surrounding divs having higher z-index.

(The framed div will contain a slideshow with elements, animated and with wierd margins, and the masking divs are supposed to hide the the texts being animated from the side.)

I'm thinking something like:

```
<div class="fullwith mask"></div>
<div class="mask leftpadding"></div>
<div id="slideshow" style="width:640px;height:405px;"></div>
<div class="mask rightpadding"></div>
<div class="fullwith mask"></div>
```

I've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SeLdq/) that by no means work, please fill the gap or tell me if I'm off the mark here.

Comment: Your first and last `div`s have class "fullwith mask" (missing the "d"). It leaves some funny whitespace, but does fixing that give you what you want? If not, you may want some nesting (but I'm not really sure).

Comment: @trojansdestroy, to fix the space problem, `max-width: 100%` can be added to `#slideshow`.